# i want to make my sms notification stay till there is a button to remove the notification

Tags: android, notifications, alert

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


               // Show Alert
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
                             "senderNum: "+ senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                toast.show();

            } // end for loop
          } // bundle is null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

}

I want to make the notification to stop till the i have pressed a button.here the notification is coming but is very short ....How can make it stay till i press abutton...please help me

Comment: You should make your own custom notification for that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing a Toast message, use something such as a `AlertDialog`, [or any other dialog of your choice](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) to interact with the user.

Remember the lifecycle when the device swaps rotation (and destroy/recreate the dialog), and you are good to go.